# Understanding MSE,R2 scores wrt different scaling methods and non intutive results

Tags: feature-scaling, mse

EDIT: Added Code and updated the metric values as my code changed

If I have the Income Statements of all the companies currently trading in the US, I would like to predict the gross profit.
I was playing with the different scalers in `scikit-learn` and comparing mean squared error and r2 metrics. I also have a separate dataframe of two companies e.g. Google, IBM, to sanity check my predictions. I use the predictions of the model, do inverse transform to get back real values and then try to sanity check if my predictions are close to the actual values.

```py
dataset = .. mostly non gaussian, unscaled raw, non zero, non null dataframe
test_dataset = ..unscaled raw, non zero, non null dataframe containing Google and IBM income sheet data. This is for my sanity test. 
# Label Column
label_column = 'grossProfit'

# Scaler Functions
def scaler_transform(scaler, x):
  df = x.copy()  
  df[df.columns] = scaler.transform(df[df.columns])
  return df

def scaler_fit(scaler, x):
  df = x.copy()  
  scaler.fit(df[df.columns])
  return scaler

def scaler_transform_inverse(scaler, x):
  df = x.copy()  
  df[df.columns] = scaler.inverse_transform(df[df.columns])
  return df


# Actual Scaling
scaler = scaler_fit(RobustScaler(), dataset)
normed_training_dataframe = scaler_transform(scaler, dataset)
normed_test_dataframe = scaler_transform(scaler, test_dataset)
training_dataframe = normed_training_dataframe
test_dataframe = normed_test_dataframe


# Ludwig
from ludwig.api import LudwigModel
final_training_dataframe = training_dataframe

# Neural Net: 4 hidden layers
model_definition = {'input_features': [{'name': 'incomeBeforeTax', 'type': 'numerical'},
  {'name': 'netIncome', 'type': 'numerical'},
  {'name': 'sellingGeneralAdministrative', 'type': 'numerical'},
  ..
  {'name': 'netIncomeApplicableToCommonShares', 'type': 'numerical'},
  {'name': 'totalRevenue', 'type': 'numerical'}],
 'output_features': [{'fc_size': 168,
   'name': 'grossProfit',
   'num_fc_layers': 4,
   'optimizer': {'type': 'mean_squared_error'},
   'type': 'numerical'}],
 'training': {'batch_size': 32,
  'epochs': 10000,
  'learning_rate': 0.004516233033842227,
  'optimizer': {'type': 'rmsprop'}}}

model = LudwigModel(model_definition)
final_train_stats = model.train(final_training_dataframe)

# Metric Calculation
mse = final_train_stats['validation'][label_column]['mean_squared_error'][-1]
print('MSE:' + str(mse))
r2 = final_train_stats['validation'][label_column]['r2'][-1]
print('R2:' + str(r2))


# Sanity Check
predict_df = model.predict(data_df=test_dataframe)

prediction_full_standardized_df = test_dataframe.copy().drop(label_column, 1)
predict_df_copy = predict_df.copy()
predict_df_copy.columns = [label_column]

prediction_full_standardized_df = prediction_full_standardized_df.reset_index(drop='True')
prediction_full_standardized_df = pd.merge(prediction_full_standardized_df, predict_df_copy, left_index=True, right_index=True)
prediction_full_standardized_df

actual_full_df = test_dataset.copy()
actual_full_df = actual_full_df.reset_index(drop='True')
actual_full_df

# Inverse Transform
prediction_full_df = scaler_transform_inverse(scaler, prediction_full_standardized_df)

diff = (prediction_full_df[label_column] / actual_full_df[label_column] - 1) * 100
diff.abs().mean(axis=0)
```

My concern is that I was expecting that a lower MSE score would give me the closest predictions but that seems not to be the case when I do a sanity check. Note, though I provide R2 values, the training is optimized for MSE as you can see in the `model_definition`

```
---
MinMaxScaler:
MSE:0.0003734849866593949
R2:-38848.26144771535
diff.abs().mean(axis=0):10952.754278227647

RobustScaler:
MSE:17474834283304.852
R2:-7199011407.460549
diff.abs().mean(axis=0): 91.40927816440639


StandardScaler:
MSE:0.021922195014768487
R2:0.0030305917889202547
diff.abs().mean(axis=0): 74.77342625156986
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show how you compute R2, but, something is very wrong here. It can only be negative if your model is very poor, and here it's very negative.

Likewise MSE is all over the place; it seems like it is not computed on unscaled values.

The `diff` is at least missing an absolute value.

I think you have further errors in the code you used to compute these. Use standard scikit classes. Don't invert the transforms yourself. Just build a pipeline of the transformations and model, and use it to fit and transform.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Owen for still answering my ill defined question :). I have updated the question with my code. I also added the abs value. I'm using Ludwig which calculates the MSE/R2 for me.

Comment: I can't really tell but I think your problem is that you are standardizing the label, which you shouldn't, and then the inverse transform is applied to a DF with columns in the wrong order

Comment: Thank you so much. re: standardizing the label, I see mixed answers. for e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/391354. Is there a way of determining when to scale labels and when not to?

Comment: Yeah OK I can see that; depends a bit on what problem you're solving. Here I think it's that you put back the DF with cols in a different order.